# Why isn't db:migrate get called as a prerequisite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have a bootstrap task, which I intend to have `db:reset` and `db:migrate` as prerequisites. I defined it like this:

```
task :bootstrap => [:environment,:"db:reset",:"db:migrate"] do ...
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
** Invoke bs:bootstrap (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:reset (first_time)
** Invoke db:drop (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:drop
** Invoke db:setup (first_time)
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:create
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:schema:load
-- create_table("projects", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0770s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.1110s
...
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
You have 1 pending migrations:
  20120109172252 CreateObjectives
Run "rake db:migrate" to update your database then try again.
```

Why isn't `db:migrate` being called, since it's listed as a prerequisite?

Comment: Are you sure that db:reset which you listed before it doesn't require that no migrations are pending and fails before it gets to db:migrate?

Comment: How should I ensure that there isn't anything in the database? I want it to be completely empty before bootstraping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like db:reset is aborting since you have pending migrations. Since db:reset will use db:schema:load to use your db/schema.rb file to reset the DB, you shouldn't really need to run migrations.

What you could do instead is put db:migrate *before* db:reset -- this would run migrations, update your schema.rb file so db:reset would use that updated version when resetting the DB (thus avoiding that pending migrations error).